# Is there a way to setup different configuration for one hystrix command based on different caller?

Tags: java, hystrix

I'm adding the flow control on existing dubbo service environment with hystrix and want to set up different thresholds for different callers on one service interface. But I cant find any information about that on the hystrix document. Please help me about this configuration.

@HystrixCommand is designed for all the callers on one command, I haven't find the way to add certain caller and its own threshold to theconfiguration

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible at least directly:

When you put a circuit breaker on some code, lets call it `foo()`, this means that you want to protect the resource accessed from `foo()`
It doesn't really matter that there are many flows that can call `foo()`, bottom line if the resource accessed from `foo()` is overwhelmed, all callers will "suffer".

So, what you can do is to define two different commands for two different places that will call `foo()` and this would mean that you separately protect these two places:

```
public class ImportantService {
    public void foo() { 
       // was protected with circuit breaker
    }
}

public class Flow1 {

    private ImportantService importantService;

    @HystrixCommand - protect with Cirquit Breaker Configuration 1 
    public void doFlow1() {
       importantService.foo();
    }  
 }


     public class Flow2 {

    private ImportantService importantService;

    @HystrixCommand - protect with Cirquit Breaker Configuration 2 
    public void doFlow2() {
       importantService.foo();
    }  
 }
```

So yes, technically its possible with such a workaround, however I suggest you to "think twice" before introducing such a configuration, whether it will achieve the goal of protecting a really important resource like I've explained above.

Comment: the example u give is from the consumer side, i am thinking about the provider side. For example I can set up another dynamic hystrixCommand Factory to create hystrix Command based on caller and its own threshold.